# How to get EL (Expression Language) content assist (autocomplete) in JSP / JSP Tags in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jsp-tags, el

Is there a way, via configuration, upgrade or a plugin to get content assist in JSP EL expressions?

e.g.

${<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> ...

or

${pageContext.<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> ...

etc...

Comment: The MyEclipse version of Eclipse does this out of the box as well as IntelliJ. I haven't been able to gt EL autocomplete to work in the free version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this one from jboss tools: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CodeAssistinJBossToolsXMLandJSPXHTMLEditors

Comment: I installed every single JBoss tool, since it was difficult to find the source of this precise functionality I was after. It turned out to be quite a bundle. Perhaps someone can narrow down the list of packages the need to be installed for this to work?

Comment: It is part of the visual page editor/richface, and I would imagine it comes with the seams plugin as well